# How to dynamically setCenter() for google maps v3?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a table with 2 columns. In the first column I have a div that contains google_map and in the second column I have a panel that its width will change after a few second. I have a marker on the map.
Problem: When I click on a button it runs setCenter(); and set center of the marker with the last size of first column. I mean the marker is not at the center of map. but I want when I use setCenter(); it automatically put the marker at the middle of map with the new position.
Actually I want to use setCenter(); dynamically when the size of columns change.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map,'click',function()
{
        map.setCenter(center);
});
```

Comment: I think I have to get the new map canvas and then use setCenter but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Provide more code in a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

On `click` event you get `MouseEvent` as argument. See google docs [for Map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map). `MouseEvent` has porperty `latLng`. So, you can use:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    map.panTo(event.latLng);
});
```

Check [example at jsBin](http://jsbin.com/oKIjUcEx/1/edit)

Comment: Error: Uncaught InvalidValueError: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: not an Object

Comment: @user2671334: most probably your map is not properly initialized. Without other code hard to say what is wrong.